# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row in 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

question with probably a simple answer.

I have 2 tables, 1 AREA table, 1 MEMBER table.Each reference the other through the non identifying foreign keys, for example the AREA table references the MEMBER table as 1 member is the president of 1 area whereas the MEMBER table references AREA table as each member belongs to an area.

The trouble starts when I try to enter data into either table as I get the error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

Its obviously something wrong with my FK set up, any tips?

Conference

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
ID  int(11) No
Name    varchar(45) No
Address varchar(45) No
President_ID    int(11) No
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  ID  0   A   No
fk_Conference_Member1_idx   BTREE   No  No  President_ID    0   A   No
Conference/Service

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
Services_ID int(11) No
Conference_ID   int(11) No
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  Services_ID 0   A   No
Conference_ID   0   A   No
fk_Services_has_Conference_Conference1_idx  BTREE   No  No  Conference_ID   0   A   No
fk_Services_has_Conference_Services_idx BTREE   No  No  Services_ID 0   A   No
Member

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
ID  int(11) No
Name    varchar(45) No
PriveligeType   int(11) No
Conference  int(11) No
Email   varchar(45) Yes NULL
PhoneNumber decimal(10,0)   Yes NULL
Address varchar(45) No
Conference_ID   int(11) No
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  ID  0   A   No
fk_Member_Conference1_idx   BTREE   No  No  Conference_ID   0   A   No
Services

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
ID  int(11) No
Name    varchar(45) No
Type    varchar(45) No
Address varchar(45) No
Email   varchar(45) Yes NULL
PhoneNumber decimal(10,0)   Yes NULL
PersonOfContact varchar(45) Yes NULL
OpeningHours    varchar(45) Yes NULL
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  ID  1   A   No

Comment: Have you declared as `UNIQUE` the fields which are referenced by the `FOREIGN KEY`s?

Comment: Please show the table structures that you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unfortunate circular reference.
I would recommend the following approach:

1. Define the area table with a nullable president foreign key
2. Insert the area's first, with a null president.
3. Insert the members, linking back to the correct area.
4. Update the areas, setting the president member id.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6420e/5)

```
-- Areas have to be inserted with null presidents, and updated later
insert into area values (1, null);
insert into member values(1, 1);
update area set presidentmemberid = 1 where areaid = 1;
```

Comment: is there way I could prevent this and is circular referencing viewed as poor in db design? @StuartLC

Comment: It's not too bad, just that your application needs to deal with the chicken and egg scenario of which data to insert first. You could split out the concern of 'president' of an area in a separate table `President(areaid, memberid)`, which I guess would allow the benefit / side effect that an area can have more than one president.